# Emojis are only in black and white in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

So I came across this problem where the emoji looked like this:

[image: Emoji in black and white]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And all I had to do to **fix** it was to go to the font colors and select **Automatic**.

As follows:

[image: Select Automatic font coloring]

End result:

[image: Emoji in correct color]

Comment: This doesn't work when you print or try to save as PDF. Emojis are printed as greyscale.

Comment: @Turkeyphant well not for me ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

Choosing Automatic didn't work for me On Win 10 using Word 365 (nor on other older versions of Word) -

BUT I was experimenting with changing colors.  **When I picked one of the THEME COLORS**  (see image)  suddenly the colors flooded back into the emojis with ANY THEME COLOR chosen (no matter which shade).  So I just chose the darkest black THEME COLOR shade to keep my text black but to allow color in my colored emojis! (the ones you can find with the WINDOWS KEY + . KEY  combination.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It worked with "automatic" for me!... (all other colours would colour it fully in that colour)

However please note that, when printing, they are black and white (even if printing or saving as PDF)...